# Debug Native Code on Motorola Droid

Tags: debugging, gdb, android-ndk

I'm trying to debug an application build with the NDK on a Motorola Droid.  I'm following the instructions [here](http://pdk.android.com/online-pdk/guide/debugging_gdb.html) and I've had success in the past on an emulator (I have root access obviously) but when I try to start

```
gdbserver :5039 --attach 1082
```

through the adb shell, I get a `gdbserver:permission denied`.  Obviously as this is a stock Droid, I don't have root access.  Is that necessary? Am I just missing something?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit** I have confirmed that this command works on the emulator. Can this be done on a nonrooted device?

**Edit 2** I have also confirmed the same `Permission Denied` errors on an EVO 4G.

**Edit 3**  I have also discovered that a production device (eg. EVO 4G or Droid) will not give me a "not found" error.  For instance, when I typed something random like `ljs` at the shell, I get `ljs: permission denied`.  The error is the same if the command exists and I can't access it (sudo - presumably) or if the command does not exist (ljs).

Comment: i'm not sure...but don't you need Android 2.2 to debug with gdb? Do you have Android 2.2 on your Droid?

Comment: I don't and as far as I remember, the gdb instructions/NDK has existed prior to 2.2.  Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: I think even non-"rooted" devices can run `su` via adb to access privileged console commands, but I haven't tried it.  If it works let me know and I'll post a proper answer.

Comment: @Walter neither `sudo` or `su` work: they both result in a `Permission Denied` error. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the r4 NDK, you shouldn't have to do a lot of this. Instead:

1. Add android:debuggable="true" in your ApplicationManifest.xml's application node
2. For any native (built with NDK) libraries, repeat #1 before building them (you should note a extra bit of information when building where ndk-build is copying a gdbserver and gdb.setup files)
3. Fire up $NDK_ROOT/ndk-gdb with your desired options (e.g.: I commonly break in Eclipse before hitting native code then attach using the -E option)

Answer (score 1):

I see no reference to 'localhost' as per

```
gdbserver :5039 --attach pid
```

in the link you've given - that is on the handset....have you forwarded the port

```
adb forward tcp:5039 tcp:5039
```

from the workstation?

Also:

```
If you can't find either special version of gdb, run find prebuilt -name 
arm-eabi-gdb in your source tree to find and run the latest version
```

Have you tried using 'arm-eabi-gdb' instead, by replacing the above gdb with the explicit version....?

Comment: I removed the `localhost` with no luck.  I haven't tried any of the versions of gdb on my host because I haven't been able to start the server on the device.